# How to print single value of a table in lua

Tags: lua, key-value, lua-table

I can't figure out how to print a single value in tab2.

I'm trying to get the same result of when I print tab1.

I don't care about the order I just need to print a single pair(get the the key and the value), or pop it from the tab2 (with something like table.remove(tab1,1))

```
tab1= {{x=1},{y=2}}
tab2= {x=3, y=4}

for k,v in pairs(tab1[1]) do
    print(k,v)
end

for k,v in pairs(tab2) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

I'm having difficult with tables, I started study three days ago so I'm a principiant.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a single value from `tab2` you do

`print(tab2["x"])` or `print(tab2["y"])`.

Or short:

`print(tab2.x)` or `print(tab2.y)`

> Thank you for your fast response. I need a way to do it when I don't
> know the key.

In order to get a single value from a table without providing a key you can use [next](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next)

```
print(next(tab2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I need a way to do it when I don't know the key. Is there a way to get the first pair of an unordered table ? For first I mean the first one lua would pick by doing for..pair loop